# Does Reiner suffer from split personality or DID?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I noticed that during two situations he behaved in an unusual way, which might mean he suffers from split personality.

I noticed this in the following scenes:

- When Reiner and Bertholdt kidnap Eren, they sit on a tall tree in the forest with Ymir.
- Also when Reiner asks Annie to take the ODM gear from Marco, then cries when he gets devoured by a titan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sense, yes.

> Reiner's psychological issues resemble those of dissociative identity disorder, in which a person's identity is fragmented into two or more distinct personality states, producing behavior changes and lapses in memory

Reiner's DID type personally started shortly after the untimely death of his old comrade. Reiner began taking on some of their personality and entwining it with his own over time.

> Following Marcel's death, Reiner began incorporating elements from his personality into his own. He became more decisive and assertive, even willing to threaten Annie and Bertolt to ensure they followed his orders, yet also deeply caring and genuinely desiring to protect them
>  [...]
>  By the time he joined the 104th Training Corps, Reiner had completely incorporated Marcel's personality into his own

[Source](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Reiner_Braun#Trivia)

Answer (score 1):

I dont won't to go into too much detail to avoid spoilers :)

but he has the symptoms of split personality, also split personality is often a result of childhood trauma.

Also there's a quote from MedicalTrialToday:

> "he condition represents someone who struggles to integrate and
> assimilate certain aspects of their own identity, which become
> disjointed over time."

Also about the Symptoms fromsame article:

> Symptoms include:
>
> - Experiencing two or more separate personalities, each with their own self-identity and perceptions.
> - A notable change in a person’s sense of self.
> - Frequent gaps in memory and personal history, which are not due to normal forgetfulness, including loss of memories, and forgetting
>   everyday events.

This perfectly captures Reiner's behaviour. He acts almost like he has 2 separate collection of memories - sometimes he acts like a regular Scout who doesn't remember himself having a mission to capture Eren.

The only factor against the split personality is the fact that Reiner can access all his memories like both of his personalities become one again.

Also, if you're not familiar with manga or season 4, here's a very minor SPOILER:

SPOILER:

> Reiner also suffers later from depression and has suicidal attempt (he puts gun into his mouth), which is something that some of patients with DID suffers from too). -

2nd SPOILER:

> There's also other explanation for his split personality - titan shifters can have memories and personality trades of shifters that had the same titan power before them. But i dont believe it's the case for reiner. END OF SPOILER

Source: https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/split-personality#risk-factors